# XStream serialization bug?

Tags: java, restlet

I'm not sure if this is a Restlet/XStream bug but when you have a resource like this

```
List<User> getUsers() {}
```

And this resource returns a single element List then the resulting JSON string is like this

```
{ "users" : { "id" : 1 } }
```

Instead of

```
{ "users" : [{ "id" : 1 }] }
```

The problem here is the result was not JSON array as expected.

Is there a workaround for this bug?